# Variable in Date command

Tags: shell, scripting, solaris

I want to use a variable inside `date` command . GNU date is not supportable in my system.
I use Sunos and when I use `date` with `-d` option it is shwoing `-d` as bad substitution.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
RELEASE_DATE="28 OCT 2018" 
RELEASE_DATE_MINUS_2=`date -"${RELEASE_DATE: -2} ${RELEASE_DATE:4:3} ${RELEASE_DATE:0:4} - 2 days" '+%Y-%m-%d'`
echo "Release is $RELEASE_DATE" 
echo "release_date-2 is $RELEASE_DATE_MINUS_2
```

I have tried the above code snippet.
I should pass the actual `release_date` which i get it form another `.cnf` file 
like `28OCT2018` with this input I should get two days before that date like `2018-10-26`.

Comment: What language is `rel_date` a variable in?

Comment: Will your input date **always** be in the same format?  Also will it pad day numbers less than 10? ie `2019JAN07` or `2019JAN7`?

Comment: What OS and/or Distribution is this running on? (Do you have GNU `date`?)

Comment: "_I have used various date command features_" care to share which ones you've tried, and how? Or do we need to guess?

Comment: "_I am getting the error in stating -d option is not a valid argument._" What command did you use, and what was the _exact_ error message? (Don't approximate.)

Comment: Note that you have an incorrect variable assignment for POSIX-type shells where no spaces are allowed around `=`

Comment: Hi Jesse , rel_date will be  fetched from some different script with .cnf extension.  And yes it will always be in this format like '2018OCT28' since i am fetching this variable from different script .cnf file. And the day will be always padded with 2 digit like 00,01, 02 etc And i am using Sunos version 5.10 version.

Comment: You may want to check if you have GNU date installed as `gdate` on your Solaris system.

Answer (score 1):

With the `zsh` shell:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
rel_date=2018OCT28
strftime -rs d %Y%b%d.%H $rel_date.12 &&
  strftime -s two_days_before %Y-%m-%d $((d - 86400*2)) || exit

echo $two_days_before
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl can be useful for this:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -slE 'say +(Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%Y%b%d") - 2 * 86_400)->ymd' -- -date="$rel_date"
```

You specify the format of the incoming date variable to parse it into a time object, do the date arithmetic, then output into the desired YYYYY-mm-dd format.

Documented here: https://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this with shell so I will assume the variable is supposed to be in shell but FYI you cannot have spaces around the `=` for a shell variable.

GNU `date` will not accept your input date in that format but will accept it like `28 OCT 2018` so using shell parameter expansion we can rearrange the date (as long as it will always be in the same format):

```
date -d "${rel_date: -2} ${rel_date:4:3} ${rel_date:0:4}"
```

Now in order to subtract 2 days we simply need to add:

```
date -d "${rel_date: -2} ${rel_date:4:3} ${rel_date:0:4} - 2 days"
```

And to have it output in your requested format

```
date -d "${rel_date: -2} ${rel_date:4:3} ${rel_date:0:4} - 2 days" '+%Y-%m-%d'
```

Comment: We don't (yet) know for sure the OP is using GNU `date`.

Comment: We don't but I have provided a GNU date solution.

Comment: Hi Jess, Thanks for your help. But even this seems to be not working .

Comment: It just tells the same bad substitution error . Below is my code snipet.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/ksh
RELEASE_DATE="28 OCT 2018"
RELEASE_DATE_MINUS_2=`date -"${RELEASE_DATE: -2} ${RELEASE_DATE:4:3} ${RELEASE_DATE:0:4} - 2 days" '+%Y-%m-%d'`
echo "Release is $RELEASE_DATE"
echo "releasE_date-2 is $RELEASE_DATE_MINUS_2"

Comment: @Sandra: That's because in your question you specify the release date will be `2018OCT28` and now you are saying it is `28 OCT 2018`.  It is very important that you are entirely accurate with everything you provide us.  Please update your question to explain what your actual data is and I will update my answer.

Comment: Hi Jesse, Thanks for your information .  My script runs under Sunos. When i try man date command it is not showing -d as a acceptable argument . And my input variable will be in this format '2018OCT28' and i just tried it in the way you informed in your last answer like '28 COT 2018' . Please help me to solve this.

Comment: @Sandra:  Please edit your question to include all the relevant details as well as clarification on the questions that have been asked in comments so that we can vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be useful to know which ksh{88,93} are you using.

According to ksh93(1) you can find something about date:

```
 printf format [ arg ... ]
 %(date-format)T
```

--practical example

```
: printf "%(%d.%m,%Y)T\n"             
11.01,2019
: printf "%(%d.%m.%Y)T\n" "2 days ago"
09.01.2019
```